# How to replace the first regex occurrence in Swift?

Tags: swift, regex, replace

How can I use the replacingOccurrences with regex and only replace the first occurrence?

Example

```
var str = "= 1 = 2 = 3"
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d+)", with: "\\\\$1", options: .regularExpression)
// prints: = \\1 = \\2 = \\3
// should print: = \\1 = 2 = 3
```

Comment: I can't think of an easy way other than putting literally every character in an array then returning after the first hit.

Comment: Why not do `"(\\d+)(.+)", with: "\\\\$1$2"`...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String.range()` will stop at the first match:

```
var str = "= 1 = 2 = 3"
if let range = str.range(of: "\\d+", options: .regularExpression) {
    let substr = str[range]
    str = str.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: "\\\\" + substr)
}

print(str)
```

Comment: You can also use `str.replaceSubrange(range, with:...)` to mutate the string.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes more convenient with Swift Regex available in Swift 5.7+

```
var str = "= 1 = 2 = 3"
str.replace(/\d+/, maxReplacements: 1) { #"\\"# + $0.output }

print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may actually use a common work-around with a bit modified regex (the idea already suggested by [@I'L'I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491278/how-to-replace-the-first-occurence-in-swift#comment75976619_44491278), but I suggest a little modification to it):

```
var str = "= 1 = 2 = 3"
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?s)([0-9]+)(.*)", with: "\\\\\\\\$1$2", options: .regularExpression)
print(str) // => = \\1 = 2 = 3
```

Two remarks:

- `(?s)([0-9]+)(.*)` - matches the first 1 or more digits (Group 1) and then captures all the rest of the string (note that `.` will match line breaks thanks to the `(?s)` inline "dotall" modifier)
- The replacement part needs 4 backslashes to replace with 1 backslash, so, you need to put 8 backslashes there to get 2 literal backslashes in the output.

A similar to [@CodeDifferent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44491478/3832970) using the string mutating [**`.replaceSubrange` method**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2853120-replacesubrange) mentioned by [@MartinR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491278/how-to-replace-the-first-occurence-in-swift#comment75979220_44491478):

```
var str = "= 123 = 256 = 378"
if let range = str.range(of: "[0-9]+", options: .regularExpression) {
    str.replaceSubrange(range, with: "\\\\" + str[range])
}
print(str) // => = \\123 = 256 = 378
```

Hints on the regex:

- To match standalone numbers (not those like in `ABC1234`) use either word boundaries (`"\\b[0-9]+\\b"`) or negative lookarounds (i.e. "(?

  Since ICU regexps are Unicode aware by default, you should consider using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` to avoid matching non-ASCII digits.