# swift replace first occurrence of a String

Tags: ios, swift, string, replace

I have the String `"Das Auto ist blau, das andere ist allerdings blau"`

I am trying to replace only the first `"blau"` with `"red"`.

I have tried it with `.replacingOccurrences`, but this does not work for me.

Comment: Note that this question existed for replacing a first regex match, and the classic answer for your question would be mostly identical, just without the `.regularExpression` option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491278/how-to-replace-the-first-regex-occurrence-in-swift

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try

```
 let str = "Das Auto ist blau, das andere ist allerdings blau"
 if let range = str.range(of:"blau") {
     print(str.replacingCharacters(in: range, with:"red"))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {

    public func replaceFirstExpression(of pattern:String,
                                   with replacement:String) -> String {
        if let range = self.range(of: pattern) {
            return self.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```